# How can I select the 1st of every month for the last 5 years in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a list of the 1st of the Month for the last 5 years. How can i do that ?? I have a select statement:

```
select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(mm,Datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0),111) as StartDate
```

but i am not sure how to get a list for every month.

Comment: SQL is a generic query language.  Every database has different functions for manipulating date and datetime values.  Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: yes i am sorry i should have put that in there

Comment: Use a `recursive cte`.

Comment: i was trying to avoid that..

Comment: Thank you though it seems like the best way for it tow work.

Comment: A couple things every database should have, a numbers table and a calendar table.  Search for `calendar table sql server` and you'll find a few dozen examples that make tasks like this trivial.

Comment: If you need to select this a lot, you can build a date Dimension table, which commonly have a column like DayOfMonth.

Answer (score 1):

```
with dates
as (
    select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) as date
    union all
    select dateadd(month, - 1, date)
    from dates
    )
select top 60 *
from dates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     with cte as ( 
select DATEFROMPARTS ( datepart(yyyy,getdate()), datepart(mm,getdate()), 1 ) as startdate 
union all 
select dateadd(month,-1,startdate) from dates 
where datediff(year,startdate,getdate()) <> 5 ) 
select CONVERT ( varchar(12), startdate , 107 ) from cte;
```

Comment: how would i add get the date name for all ?

Comment: use below query for datename:
 

with cte
as
(
         select DATEFROMPARTS ( datepart(yyyy,getdate()), datepart(mm,getdate()), 1 ) as startdate
         union all
         select dateadd(month,-1,startdate)
         from dates
         where datediff(year,startdate,getdate()) <> 5
)
select CONVERT ( varchar(12), startdate , 107 )
from cte;